# C++ crashing when passing pointer to function

Tags: c++

what i am trying to do is display my pointer to an array of objects. here is my main program, the function it crashes at is listAll(). if i only enter one object it works, but when i enter a second one it crashes. i am at a loss of what is going wrong. problem occurs after picking menuOption 1 twice and then trying to call list all. i see that the array size is not being increased..

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

#include "fileStuff.h"

bool menu();
bool menuOptions(int option);
void fileIO();
void listAll(interact * obs, int arryO);

int main() 
{ 

    bool isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning)
    {
        isRunning = menu();
    }
return 0; 
}

bool menu()
{
    int option = 0;
    cout << "1: add new backpack. " << endl
        << "2: delete a backpack "<< endl
        << "3: sort ascending by id " << endl
        << "4: sort descending by id " << endl
        << "5: list all backpacks " << endl
        << "6: quit" << endl;
    cin >> option;
    return menuOptions(option);
}

bool menuOptions(int option)
{

    static int arrayO = 0;
    static interact *obs = new interact[arrayO];
    fileStuff test;
    int tempBagId = 0, tempInvSpaces = 0, tempAmtOfItemsInInv = 0;
    double tempInvMaxWeight = 0.0;
    string tempBagType, tempBagCondish;
    int t = 0 ;
    int i = 0;
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "bagId? ";
        cin >> tempBagId;
        cout << "How many inv spaces? ";
        cin >> tempInvSpaces;
        cout << "How much weight can the bag hold? ";
        cin >> tempInvMaxWeight;
        (obs + arrayO)->setBagId(tempBagId);
        (obs + arrayO)->setInvSpaces(tempInvSpaces);
        (obs + arrayO)->setInvMaxWeight(tempInvMaxWeight);
        cout << "all stored" << endl;
        arrayO++;
        break;
    case 2:
        //listmanager delete one

        //arrayO--;
        break;
    case 3:
        //sort ascending by id
        break;
    case 4:
        //sort descending by id
        break;
    case 5:
        //list all
        listAll(obs, arrayO);
        break;

    case 6:
        obs = NULL;
        delete obs;
        return false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


void listAll(interact * obs, int arryO)
{
int i = 0;
cout << i << endl;
cout << arryO << endl;

}
```

below is the gists of my class.

```
#include "listManager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

interact::interact()
{
    bagId = 0;
    invSpaces = 0;
    invMaxWeigt = 0;

}

void interact::setBagId(int id)
{
    bagId = id;
}
void interact::setInvSpaces(int spaces)
{
    invSpaces = spaces;
}

void interact::setInvMaxWeight(double weight)
{
    invMaxWeigt = weight;
}

int interact::getBagId()
{
    return bagId;
}
int interact::getInvSpaces()
{
    return invSpaces;
}

double interact::getInvMaxWeight()
{
    return invMaxWeigt;
}
```

Comment: The static variables are initialized before `main` is executed.  Before `main`, the value of `arrayO` is zero, so the array `obs` is allocated zero bytes.  Does this really need to be static?

Comment: `listAll()` prints two `int`s. What do you mean it crashes there?

Comment: Rather than using the notation, `(obs + arrayO)->`, you could use `obs[arrayO].`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Dynamic initialization of local static variables takes place the first time the line is reached.  Not "before main is executed".

Comment: Michael (OP), You appear to believe that the array is somehow linked to the variable used in the size expression when it was first allocated, such that incrementing that variable will expand the array.  But it doesn't work like that.  The size of an allocated object never changes.  And even if it did work that way, you try to write into the array before increasing `arrayO`.

Comment: @BenVoigt how would i accomplish a array of dynamic size? which is what arrayO suppose to do, was make it so i could have an array of an dynamic size

Comment: Well, you can use `std::vector<interact>` which has functions such as `push_back` that increase the size (actually, it's too large to begin with, and keeps track of both memory size and *used* size).  Or say `delete[] obs; obs = new interact[arrayO + 1];` when you need the size to increase.  But just `arrayO++;` has no effect on the size of the array previously created.

Comment: @BenVoigt sadly its a school project and im not allowed to use vectors. so to change the size of the array i would need to delete the pointer and create a new one? would everything currently in there be deleted?

Comment: @MichaelLapan Yeah, you need to allocate a larger array, then copy all the elements over. Just the way people did it long long ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
static int arrayO = 0;
static interact *obs = new interact[arrayO];
```

This will create a dynamic array of 0 length. As Ben stated, the pointer will never change.

The crash is probably caused by trying to access it after increasing the index (`arrayO++;`), after that it will just be accessing out of bounds memory.

Comment: 0 length is legal, but then there is nothing to be accessed

Comment: Yeah, Ben is right. Just start from scratch. This will go nowhere, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your `obs` points to an array with size zero:

```
static int arrayO = 0;
static interact *obs = new interact[arrayO];
```

and never is changed to point to anything larger.

Therefore every attempt to subscript it is an array overrun.

Comment: @Moi: That doesn't change `obs`!!!!!  It still points to the same size-zero array.  (read my comment below the question)